# sql server 2005 xml update query chinese characters

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, cjk

I am trying to update the value of a tag with Chinese characters. However it does not add the chinese characters. Instead it adds "???" .
e.g. update table  set col.modify('replace value of (/tag/text())[1] with "我"') where ..
Any help is much appreciated

thanks
Ben

Comment: @unknown: I moved another question of yours (Sql server 2005 awe) to serverfault.com where hopefully it will get responses from people who know a little more about it.

Answer (score 4):

For international characters like this you usually want to use N'this is my data' to signify it is unicode/nchar. Otherwise it is treated as char, and I'm assuming the db collation can't support the characters you are submitting. Try to just do

```
select 'my chars'
```

and see if you still get question marks, I would assume so.

EDIT - here is an example that confirms my suggestion works:

```
declare @x xml
set @x = N'<tag>abc</tag>'
set @x.modify (N'replace value of (/tag/text())[1] with "我"') 
select @x
```

I see the symbol when I select out the xml, and I verified that before and after the character is 0x1162 (proves the data is intact).

Comment: i am trying to update the xml data . The updates work for nvarchar datatypes but if i try to update a xml datatype the update does not work

Comment: @poster - See the example I have edited in. This does work, so you must be doing something else wrong if this approach still gives you trouble. Give us more details if you still have issues.

Comment: I am sending the data into an stored proc . The datatype is nvarchar. still it it saving as ???

Comment: update table set col.modify('replace value of (/tag/text())[1] with sql:variable("@data")')

the datatype of @data is nvarchar

Answer (score 2):

Are you using unicode strings?  Those start with a capital N, like:

```
update yourtable 
set yourvalue = N'your chinese characters' 
where id = yourid
```

Comment: i am trying to update the xml data . The updates work for nvarchar datatypes but if i try to update a xml datatype the update does not work

Comment: Could you post the table definitions and example XML?  I can't read your mind ;)

Comment: update table set col.modify('replace value of (/tag/text())[1] with sql:variable("@data")') the datatype of @data is nvarchar